# Building a pure server-side rest client using core 2 and refit

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, refit

I'm currently working on a pure server-side solution to consume an existing rest API, authenticated with a JWT token, in ASP.NET Core 2.

I have a Core 2 MVC project set up and included refit to to consume the api.

What I ideally want to do is to 1. Use the Refit HttpClientFactory libraries to sent a request to fetch the jwt token on the api and 2. include the token in all subsequent api calls.

I was looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465983/where-to-store-bearer-token-in-mvc-from-web-api?answertab=votes#tab-top%20post) and it is quite similar as to what Im looking to do but it needs to be a core 2 based solution.

I've already got a working solution using refit to get the jwt token from /api/login and storing it in a session variable, but this doesnt feel like the right way of doing it.

```
var client = new RestClient("localhost:5000/api/login");    
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);    
    request.AddJsonBody("User Model that I created");    
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");    
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;    
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);    
//Store the response token in session    

//Subsequent calls    
var client = new RestClient("localhost:5000/api/values");    
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);    
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer TOKEN_FROM_SESSION_STORAGE");    
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");    
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Have someone maybe worked on something like this before, just to nudge me in the right direction ?