# How to pass authorization token to GET method to access authorized resource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, http-token-authentication

I am new to Token Based authentication. With reference to below links, I am trying to understand Token Based authentication.

- http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

If the user credentials are valid, I am getting the desired token.

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]User user)
    {
        if(user.Username == "hello" && user.Password == "123")
        {
            var accessTokenResponse = GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(user.Username);

            return accessTokenResponse.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "User invalid";
        }
    }
```

Generated token

> TWC1Q2rrenZC2p78KPnS4JblcepCg6q3XuxqBQIh7L003npbb6hlBAOYGRN03OvY_O55GWFkZp7UfCmhCgH9Z4rBsjvIrp8gyCp4HmxpP4axVKk10NM9fiG2ctgZWeSbw1jNOor42Wk3yMufbs4xP0RlNuvdpLtBLir52g9rPF053kiJtYryNGzPsbibXHRrNoy0wOR2384uLAJ5pNE9s1DwYpdPKB9uOLSAGhDQOVU,

Now when I try to access the secured resources

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    // GET api/orders/5
    public string Get()
    {
        return "This is a secure resource";
    }
```

I get "Access Denied Error".

How do I use the token to access such resources.

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this answer may give you some more insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661090/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-without-any-user-interface/38670221#38670221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually you would not implement the token endpoint as a POST method in your controller, but create a separate class (`SimpleAuthorizationServerProvide`) for it as shown in the above mentioned tutorial.
If everything is setup correctly, you have to add an Authorization header to your http request

```
Authorization: Bearer TWC1Q2rrenZC2p78KP...
```

and get a reply with status code 200(OK)

To get a token send a request (for example with the tool [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)) to your token endpoint
e.g. if your service is running on localhost on port 52180 it looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:52180/token 

grant_type=password&username=admin&password=123&client_id=abc
```

the grant_type part is the request body.
When you post the above request, you'll reach the token endpoint. Just as Taiseer wrote in Step 12 of the tutorial.

When you put a breakpoint at `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` that should be reached as soon as you sent the above request.

The usual flow is:
- client requests a token from http://localhost:52180/token

- server authenticates user credentials in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials and issues a token
- client reads the access_token from the token response
- client adds an authorization header containing the access_token to a request

  ```
  http://localhost:52180/api/orders

  Authorization: Bearer TWC1Q2rrenZC2p78KP...
  ```
- server reads Authorization header and grants access (if token is valid)
- server processes request, eg, the GET request
- client receives status 200 and desired data

The api controller shown above looks ok
The [Authorize] attribute is all you need in your controller. That adds an AuthorizationFilter to the http request pipeline, which handles the authorization for you when the client adds the above mentioned Authoriztion header to the request.

Comment: Agreed. But how do I add Authorization token to Get order. Please suggest

Comment: I Cross checked everything seems matching.

Comment: you say, everything is as it in the tutorial, but it's not working? Where do you send your token request? Should be the path configured in TokenEndpointPath, eg. http:/localhost:<yourportnumber>/token. Not to public string Post([FromBody]User user), you don't need that.

Comment: put a breakpoint at GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context), that's the method that should be hit when you send the token request

Comment: I have adding the relevant code-snippets here. 
1) https://codepaste.net/7uy6po  2)https://codepaste.net/8otsfg 3)https://codepaste.net/n286c7

Comment: Can you pleaseeeeeeee have a look at the above links once? Sincere Thanks

Comment: I uploaded the complete solution for quick reference here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/94z61n7nbe2ango/Token_123.zip?dl=0 Please check

Comment: I think the LoginController is the problem and  not needed at all, because you bypass the OWIN middleware. Please read and reply to my last two comments above.

Comment: I read your comment of redirecting to /token but how to do it? I am really going crazy please edit the code-snippet, because its been now 2 days I am setting up this.

Comment: Great. I reached the same point I redirected to /ticket & GrantResourceOwnerCredentials() got hit while validating the credentials & got the token also. But still I got _Authorization has been denied for this request._

Comment: checked your code: OAuthBearerOptions in ConfigureOAuth is empty. Refer to step 9 in the tutorial, maybe that's the problem

Comment: From wherever you are calling your resource, probably using HttpClient I presume, are you adding the auth token you received in the Authorization Header? Unless you do this your resource wont receive it and wont let you access any authorized endpoint.

Comment: @jps, can you please share your inputs on this??