# How to set header as token request OAuth by using authentication filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I'm developing an OAuth based Web API application.
How do I set the header as token I received from OAuth request by using authentication filter?

Reference link:
[Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)

I'm trying to check all type of methods but it's not working for me:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");

context.Request.Headers.Add("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
```

My API call source code is:

```
[BasicAuthenticator]
[HttpGet]   
[Authorize]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

and I'm getting the response:

> {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

My token generated code is as below:

```html
public class BasicAuthenticator : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple { get; set; } 
    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var req = context.Request;
        var reqHeader = context.Request.Headers;
        if (!reqHeader.Contains("Authorization"))
        {
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "grant_type", "password" ),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "username", "xxxx" ),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "Password", "xxxx" )
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            var client1 = new HttpClient();
            var response = client1.PostAsync("http://localhost:56672/" + "Token", content).Result;
            var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var obj = JObject.Parse(responseBody.Result);
            var tokenVal = (string)obj["access_token"];
            client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenVal);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661090/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-without-any-user-interface/38670221#38670221

Comment: Where are you generating the Token? In the server attribute BasicAuthenticator? The client has to send the Token in order to authenticate. Check the link in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the Active auth scheme on your API. Try replacing `[Authorize]` with `[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]`.

Comment: ActiveAuthenticationSchemes missing assembly reference ?