# Mvc Api get credentials from request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm having a heck of a time finding anything on this, even though I would think it's pretty straight forward...

I'm developing an API using .NET MVC 4.5. I want the end user to be able to send a request like (PowerShell):

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, 
$securePassword)
$doc = $webclient.DownloadString("http://localhost:60023/api/getData?id=200")
```

But I don't know how to pull the Credentials from the request in my application.

My controller looks like:

```
namespace App.Controllers
{
    public IEnumerable<MyStruct> Get(int id)
    {
        // TODO: get credentials from request

        // validate credentials
        // code to create IEnumerable<MyStruct>
        return DataList;
    }
}
```

So far, everything works if I hard-code the credentials, all I need to figure out is how to get the credentials from the end-user's `$webclient.Credentials`.

I'm sure this has been discussed before, but I've been searching for hours and can't find the answer.

**Am I Way Off?**

Is this not a good way to go about authenticating API requests? I know that there is an [Authorize] attribute that can use the built-in authentication system, but my app uses custom login verification, so I don't think that will work. Is there a reason verifying credentials within the Controller method in the manner that I want is a bad idea?

Comment: But why the down-vote? A little explanation would be nice...

Comment: There is a better and secure token based mechanism instead of passing username and password inside header on every request. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661090/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-without-any-user-interface) is an example. *Btw, I did not down vote your question.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically `MVC` is not used for API work. While `MVC` can handle serving API calls, Microsoft has an `MVC` like product called `WebApi` that is more geared to serving an API, such as returning JSON or XML instead of a view.

In both `MVC` and `WebApi`, handling authentication and authorization within methods is not advised. While it works, it opens you up to forgetting to secure an API call.  Therefore Microsoft made the `AuthenticationFilter` and `AuthorizationFilter` attributes. These allow you to mark which APIs or Views to secure by Method, Class, or Application.

To access basic credentials from a request in `MVC`, you would access the Authorization header. This will be a string in the form of `Basic [Base64Encoded, colon delimited strings]`.

The following code shows a rough example of how to read the credentials:

```
public ActionResult TestView()
{
    bool isAuthenticated;
    var base64Header = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    //The header is a string in the form of "Basic [base64 encoded username:password]"
    if (base64Header != null)
    {
        var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(base64Header);
        if (authHeader != null
            && authHeader.Scheme.Equals("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && authHeader.Parameter != null)
        {
            //Decode the username:password pair
            var credentialPair = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64string(authHeader.Parameter));

            //Split into pieces
            var credentials = credentialPair.Split(new [] {":"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
            var userName = credentials[0];
            var plainTextPassword = credentials[1];
            isAuthenticated = SomeAuthenticator.Authenticate(userName, password);
        }
    }
    if (isAuthenticated)
       return Foo();
    else
       RedirectResult("your login view");
}
```

It would be best to insert this code into an `AuthenticationFilter` however. This grants you the ability to turn authorization on/off by method, class, or application.

```
public class CustomAuthFilter : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        var header = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (!Authenticate(header))
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
       filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(@"https:\\foo\YourLoginPage");
    }

    private bool Authenticate(string rawAuthorizationHeader)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rawAuthorizationHeader != null)
            {
                var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(rawAuthorizationHeader);
                if (authHeader != null
                    && authHeader.Scheme.Equals("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    && authHeader.Parameter != null)
                {
                    var credentialPair = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter));
                    var credentials = credentialPair.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    var userName = credentials[0];
                    var plainTextPassword = credentials[1];
                    return SomeAuthenticator.Authenticate(userName, plainTextPassword);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then consumed by

```
[CustomAuthFilter] //Secure all methods in the class
public class SecureApiController
{

    public ActionResult SecuredApiCall()
    {
        return Foo();
    }

    public ActionResult AnotherSecuredCall()
    {
        return Bar();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult UnsecuredApiCall()
    {
        return UnsecureFoo();
    }
}
```

Note that in typical Microsoft fashion, *Authentication* and *Authorization* are two different things. You will need to setup an Authorization filter if you want to secure an API by more than "this user has an account".

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, I've since found a post regarding adding a web api to an existing MVC project [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project)