# .NET Core Middleware: How to access request credentials?

Tags: c#, .net-core, middleware, webrequest, httpcontext

For testing, I am sending the request with credentials using

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Then catch these on the other app using .NET Core's Middleware

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Accessing the request in `context.Request` is successful but what I am still looking is where does the credentials be found inside `context`?

Or there are other way around?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359246/mvc-api-get-credentials-from-request). The credentials are encoded in the Authorization header.

```
bool isAuthenticated;
var base64Header = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
//The header is a string in the form of "Basic [base64 encoded username:password]"
if (base64Header != null)
{
    var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(base64Header);
    if (authHeader != null
        && authHeader.Scheme.Equals("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        && authHeader.Parameter != null)
    {
        //Decode the username:password pair
        var credentialPair = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64string(authHeader.Parameter));

        //Split into pieces
        var credentials = credentialPair.Split(new [] {":"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var userName = credentials[0];
        var plainTextPassword = credentials[1];
        isAuthenticated = SomeAuthenticator.Authenticate(userName, password);
    }
}
if (isAuthenticated)
   return Foo();
else
   RedirectResult("your login view");
```

Comment: It is the same approach that I did. :)